# The middle-square method

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

#### Introduction

The *middle-square* method is used for the generation of pseudorandom numbers. However, this is not a good method in practice, since its period is usually very short and has some severe weaknesses. How does this work? Let's take an example:

For the seed, we pick `123456`:

```
Seed     123456
```

The seed squared (seed × seed), is equal to:

```
Seed²  15241383936
```

We started with a **6-digit** number. That means that the seed squared should deliver a **12-digit** number. If this is not the case, leading zeroes are added to compensate:

```
Seed²  015241383936
```

We then take the middle part of the number, with **the same size** as the seed:

```
Seed²  015241383936
          ^^^^^^
```

This is then our **new seed**: `241383`. We repeat the same process as shown above. We get the following:

```
0:     123456
    015241383936
       |    |
1:     241383
    058265752689
       |    |
2:     265752
    070624125504
       |    |
3:     624125
    389532015625
       |    |
4:     532015
    283039960225
       |    |
5:     039960
    001596801600
       |    |
6:     596801
```

And this keeps on in a while... Now we know what the middle-square method is, let's get to the challenge:

---

#### The Task

Every seed **has** a *period*. The period of a *n*-digit seed cannot be longer than 8<sup>n</sup>. For example, the seed `82`. This would give the following sequence:

```
82 > 72 > 18 > 32 > 02 > 00 > 00 > 00 > 00 > 00
|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|___...
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

You can see that the period is equal to **5**, before containing the same digit again. Your task is, **when given a seed greater than 0 containing no leading zeroes, output the period of the seed**. So, in this case, you need to output `5`.

Another example is: `24`, which gives the following:

```
24 > 57 > 24
|____|____|___...
0    1    2
```

As you can see, not all sequences end in `0`. This cycle has a period of *1*.

---

#### Test cases

```
Input   >   Output
24      >   1
82      >   5
123456  >   146
8989    >   68
789987  >   226
```

The pastebins with the sequences for [123456](http://pastebin.com/MLxM9Pup), [8989](http://pastebin.com/HM1AhQFq), [789987](http://pastebin.com/X42VaX0r)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

**You can assume that the input will never have an uneven number of digits.**

Comment: Nit pick: That's not a period. Period implies that the sequence eventually goes back it its initial state.  `24` is periodic (with period 2, I'd say), `82` is *eventually periodic* (with period 1).

Comment: So "period" is the 0-index of the last state which is different from all previous states?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that is correct. My mathematical knowledge isn't the best :p.

Comment: It'd be more like 'the number of iterations before it stabilizes'

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes See this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8zqkyKHr). Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Just did some tests for 2-digit numbers, and found some interesting results.  It turns out there are only 5 possible end results for all numbers 0-99.  It will either stabilize on `0` (most common: 62% of all inputs), or stabilize on `10` (19%), `50` (1%), `60` (15%), or an endless loop of `24` and `57` (3%).  `50` is only possible if you start with `50`.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I also found [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Middle_square_method_2_digits.svg) diagram, which also might be interesting :).

Comment: @Adnan - Yes, I more or less derived the same diagram myself.  I thought about posting it, but it'd need to be as an answer to this challenge, and I don't have one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 18 bytes

```
³DL⁵*
²:¢½¤%¢µÐĿL’
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrNETOKBtSoKwrI6wqLCvcKkJcKiwrXDkMS_TOKAmQ&input=&args=MTIzNDU2)

#### How it works

```
³DL⁵*         Helper link. No arguments.

³             Yield the original input.
 D            Convert from integer to base 10.
  L           Get l, the length of the decimal representation.
   ⁵*         Compute 10 ** l.


²:¢½¤%¢µÐĿL’  Main link. Input: n (integer)

²             Square n.
  ¢½¤         Call the helper link and take the square root of the result.
 :            Integer division; divide the left result by the right one.
      ¢       Call the helper link.
     %        Take the left result modulo the right one.
       µ      Convert the previous chain into a link, and begin a new chain.
        ÐĿ    Repeat the previous chain until the results are no longer unique,
              updating n in each iteration. Collect the intermediate results.
          L   Get the length of the list of results.
           ’  Decrement.
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Pure bash, <s>162 131 116 113</s> 107

Saved 3 bytes by using `$c`...

Thanks [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/179039?noredirect=1) for help me to save 6 more bytes.

`---- begin middleSquare ----`

```
for((b=$1;i[c=10#$b]<2;)){ a=${#b}
printf -v b %0$[a*2]d $[c*c]
b=${b:a/2:a};((i[10#$b]++))
};echo ${#i[@]}
```

`---- end middleSquare ----`

```
for testCase in 24 82 123456 8989 789987 111111;do
    printf "%12s: " $testCase
    bash middleSquare $testCase
  done
          24: 2
          82: 5
      123456: 146
        8989: 68
      789987: 226
      111111: 374
```

#### Square formated, 131

`---- begin middleSquare ----`

```
for((b=$1;i[
10#$b]<2;1))
do a="${#b}" 
printf -v b\
 %0$[a*2]d \
$[10#$b**2];
b=${b:a/2:a}
((i[10#$b]++
));done;ech\
o ${#i[@]:0}
```

`---- end middleSquare ----`

```
for testCase in 24 82 123456 8989 789987 111111;do
    printf "%12s: %9d\n" $testCase $(
        bash middleSquare $testCase)
  done
          24:         2
          82:         5
      123456:       146
        8989:        68
      789987:       226
      111111:       374
```

#### Old but with fancy output, 162

`---- begin middleSquare ----`

```
for((b=$1;i[10#$b
]<2;1))do a=${#b}
printf -v b %0$[a
*2]d  $[10#$b**2]
b=${b:a/2:a};((i[
10#$b]++));print\
f "%9d %s\n" ${#\
i[@]} $b;done;ec\
ho -- ${#i[@]} --
```

`---- end middleSquare ----`

```
bash middleSquare 24
        1 57
        2 24
        2 57
-- 2 --

for testCase in 24 82 123456 8989 789987 111111
    do while read f v f
        do r=$v;done < <(
        bash middleSquare $testCase)
    printf "%12s: %11d\n" $testCase $r
  done
          24:           2
          82:           5
      123456:         146
        8989:          68
      789987:         226
      111111:         374
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python <s>3</s> 2, <s>139</s> <s>114</s> 97 bytes

Thanks to Seeq for golfing off 25 bytes and thanks to Dennis for golfing off 17 bytes! Code:

```
s=`input()`;u=[];l=len(s)/2
while not s in u:u+=[s];s=`int(s)**2`.zfill(l*4)[l:3*l]
print~-len(u)
```

Can definitely be golfed further. This was also the code used to make the test cases :P.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 82 bytes

```
f=(n,p={},m=-1,l=n.length)=>p[n]?m:f(`${n*n+100**l}`.substr(l/2+1,l,p[n]=1),p,++m)
```

Accepts input in the form of a string, e.g. "82", and returns an integer. Simple tail recursive technique to check each seed in turn against a hash of seeds that have already been seen. I add 100**l to the square to ensure a consistent length.

Comment: @Downgoat Accepts input in the form of a **string**.

Comment: oh yeah, I guess I can't read :|

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes No, that doesn't work when the intermediate value begins with enough zeros. (This is why I "wasted" 7 bytes adding 100**l.)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes There are cases where it doesn't work, for instance try following the chain from 5288.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 33 <s>35</s> <s>40</s> bytes

```
`t0)2^10GVnXK2/^/k10K^\vtun@>]n2-
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHQwKTJeMTBHVm5YSzIvXi9rMTBLXlx2dHVuQD5dbjIt&input=MTIzNDU2)

```
`           % do...while
  t         %   duplicate. Take input implicitly on first iteration
  0)        %   pick last value of array
  2^        %   square
  10        %   push 10
  GVn       %   number of digits of input
  XK        %   copy that to clipboard K
  2/        %   divide by 2
  ^         %   power
  /k        %   divide and floor. This removes rightmost digits from the square value
  10K^      %   10 ^ number of digits of input
  \         %   modulo. This takes the central part of the squared number
  v         %   concatenate this new number to array of previous numbers
  tun@>     %   does the number of unique values exceed the iteration index?
]           % if so: next iteration. Else: exit loop
n2-         % desired result is the amount of numbers minus 2. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
tl.us_<>_`^N2/lz2lzsz
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tl.us_%3C%3E_%60%5EN2%2Flz2lzsz&input=123456&test_suite_input=24%0A82%0A123456%0A8989%0A789987&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tl.us_%3C%3E_%60%5EN2%2Flz2lzsz&input=123456&test_suite_input=24%0A82%0A123456%0A8989%0A789987&debug=0&test_suite=1)

edit: Found the edge case `1000`, which didn't worked with my previous code. Fixed it for 1 byte.

#### Explanation:

```
tl.us_<>_`^N2/lz2lzsz   implicit: z = input string
  .u               sz   apply the following instructions to N, starting with N = int(z), 
                        until it runs into a loop:
          ^N2              square it
         `                 convert it to a string
        _                  reverse order
       >     /lz2          remove the first len(z)/2
      <          lz        remove everything but the first len(z)  
     _                     reverse order
    s                      convert to int
  .u                   returns the list of all intermediate values
 l                     compute the length of this list
t                      minus 1
```

Comment: any reason to use `sz` instead of `Q`?

Comment: @user1737909 If I use `Q`, I have to replace all the `lz` with ``l`Q``s.

Comment: mh, it seems surprising Pyth doesn't share `input`. I guess it's really meant to allow for a second stdin read..?

Comment: @user1737909 Yes. The only possibility to share input is with `.z` and `.Q`, though they read multiple lines of input and store them in lists. But I haven't actually seen somebody use this feature. It's only 1 byte to evaluate a string or to stringify a number.

Comment: Okay, so you can read stdin at most 4 times in Pyth, `Qz.Q.z`?

Comment: @user1737909 No, you can also read input using `E` (evaluated input) and with `w` (string input). The four ways you described read input at the beginning of the program and autoinitialize them to the variables `Q`, `z`, `.Q`, `.z`. The other two `E` and `w` don't initialize the input to some variable. Just try this: http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=E%0AQ%0AE%0Aw%0Aw%0Az&input=first+line%0A123456%0A1%0A2%0Atest%0Ahallo&debug=0

Comment: Thanks – would it make sense then to have `z` and `Q` share input?

Comment: I don't think so. Quite often you need to read a string and a number and use both data multiple times. So it's quite handy to have 2 auto-assigning variables. It's quite rare though, that you need to share memory. And as I said, converting is only 1 byte. If you want to talk more, we should probably switch to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24159/pyth instead of spamming the comments.

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 184 bytes

```
WITH v(v,p,n)AS(SELECT:1,'0',-1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT SUBSTR(LPAD(POWER(v,2),LENGTH(v)*2,0),LENGTH(v)/2+1,LENGTH(v)),v,n+1 FROM v)CYCLE v SET c TO 1 DEFAULT 0 SELECT MAX(n)FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(v,p,n) AS
(
  SELECT :1,'0',-1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(LPAD(POWER(v,2),LENGTH(v)*2,0), LENGTH(v)/2+1, LENGTH(v)),v,n+1 FROM v
)
CYCLE v SET c TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT MAX(n) FROM v;
```

It uses the build in cycle detection to stop the recursivity.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 64 bytes

```
f(n,A=[],p=10^endof(dec(n)))=n∈A?-1:f(n^2÷√p%p,[A...n],p)+1
```

Try it with [Coding Ground](http://goo.gl/0osTMa).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 80 bytes

```
(a=10^⌊Log10@#+1⌋;Length@NestWhileList[⌊#^2/a^.5⌋~Mod~a&,#,Unequal,All]-2)&
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 37 bytes

```
q{__,W*:D;~_*sD2/<D>]___|=:A;~A}g],((
```

Ran into an annoying stack-order issue that I can't immediately see how to resolve. It's also incredibly slow.

How it works:
Each iteration pushes the new value on top of the stack, then we wrap the stack into an array, and see if it's the same as its union with itself (to see if it has any duplicate elements). When it has duplicate elements, stop, and see how many elements are in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 82 bytes

```
def f(n,A=[],l=0):l=l or len(`n`)/2;return-(n in A)or-~f(n*n/10**l%100**l,A+[n],l)
```

Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/FC1SfF).

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 124 bytes

```
def f(s,p=-1,n=0,m=[]):
 x=len(str(s))*2
 while n not in m:m+=[s];y=str(s*s).zfill(x);n=int(y[x/4:x*3/4]);p+=1;s=n
 return p
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBSCRIPT, 131 bytes

```
s=inputbox(c):l=len(s):do:t=t&","&s:s=space(l*2-len(s*s))&s*s:s=mid(s,l/2+1,l):i=i+1:loop until instr(t,","&s)>0:msgbox i-1
```

Best I could do with vbscript, first time poster so go easy on me!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange! Great first post! I edited the formatting of your post a little bit to make it more readable and to conform to our standards more. Happy golfing!