# The Squaring Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

Each term in the squaring sequence, \$x_n\$, is created by taking \$x_{n-1}\$, squaring it, and removing all but the first four digits.

The sequence always begins with \$x_1 = 1111\$. Squaring this yields \$1234321\$, so \$x_2 = 1234\$

The first few terms are:

```
1111
1234
1522
2316
5363
...
```

---

## The Challenge

Your task is to, given a non-negative integer \$n\$, calculate \$x_n\$. You may submit a full program which performs I/O, or a function which takes \$n\$ as a parameter.

Your solution can be zero or one indexed, as long as you specify which.

Because all the terms in this sequence are shorter than 5 digits, your code should be as short as possible too. Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) loopholes apply.

May the best golfer win!

---

## Test Cases

*Note: These are 1-indexed.*

```
1   -> 1111
8   -> 6840
15  -> 7584
20  -> 1425
80  -> 4717
```

Comment: Here's a [related link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73756/the-middle-square-method) :)

Comment: This sequence could find use as a pseudo-random number generator (although it's not very secure).

Comment: May we output as a string?

Comment: @ophact IO is flexible.

Comment: Any OEIS link for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Code:

```
$Fn4×4£
```

Explanation:

```
$        # Push 1 and the input
 F       # Input times do...
  n      #   Square the number
   4×    #   Repeat that string 4 times
     4£  #   Take the first four characters
         # Output the last computed number
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JEZuNMOXNMKj&input=ODA)

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds :(.

Comment: `×4£` can be `∍` now for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 36 bytes

```
f=n=>--n?(f(n)**2+f).slice(0,4):1111
```

This is a great example of abusing type coercion: `**` converts both its arguments to numbers, and `+` converts both its arguments to strings unless they're both numbers. This means that `f(n)**2+f` first converts `f(n)` to a number and squares it, then concatenates the result with the string representation of `f`. We can then use `.slice` to retrieve the first 4 chars of the string.

Here are a few alternate approaches that don't use strings:

```
f=(n,x=1111)=>x<1e4?--n?f(n,x*x):x:f(n,x/10|0)
f=n=>--n?(x=f(n))*x/(x>3162?1e4:1e3)|0:1111
```

#### Test snippet

```js
let f=n=>--n?(Math.pow(f(n),2)+f).slice(0,4):1111
```

```html
<input id=I type="number" step="1" min="1" value="1"><button onclick="console.log(f(I.value))">Run</button>
```

Note: this uses `Math.pow` because `**` isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: If we can output as a string, then `n=>n?(''+f(n-1)**2).slice(0,4):1111` should work for 35 bytes

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 44 Bytes

<s><s>I'd like to get rid of the clunky `if` if possible, but I think an `exec` could be shorter..</s> Turns out for the moment that `exec` is shorter.</s> Wrong again! The recursive function returns. This is one-indexed.

```py
f=lambda n:1111*(n<2)or int(`f(n-1)**2`[:4])
```

An aleternative 46-byte solution with `exec`:

```py
s=1111;exec's=int(`s*s`[:4]);'*input();print s
```

An alternative 49-byte recursive solution:

```py
f=lambda n,s=1111:s*0**n or f(n-1,int(`s*2`[:4]))
```

<sup>Thanks to Flp.Tkc for saving a byte by reminding me that squaring doesn't need exponentiation :)</sup>

Comment: Another 46 bytes solution: ``f=lambda n:1111if n<2else int(`f(n-1)**2`[:4])``

Comment: @daHugLenny that can actually be 45: https://repl.it/EejD

Comment: @Flp.Tkc And that can actually be 44 ;)

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 40 bytes

```
((iterate(read.take 4.show.(^2))1111)!!)
```

It's a 0-based sequence. Usage example: `((iterate(read.take 4.show.(^2))1111)!!) 79` -> `4717`.

How it works:

```
iterate (   ) 1111               -- repeatedly apply a function starting
                                 -- with 1111 and collect the results in a list
                                 -- the function is
           (^2)                  -- square
        show                     -- turn into string
     take 4                      -- take the first 4 chars
  read                           -- turn back to number
                     !!          -- finally pick the nth element from the list
```

Answer (score 6):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 19 bytes

```
4é1Àñ|C="*"
5|D
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=NMOpMcOAw7F8QxI9EiIqEiIKGzV8RA&input=&args=Mg)

This uses 0-based indexing.

Of course, since numbers aren't exactly V's *forte*, this isn't very golfy. However, it does show one nice advantage V has over vim. You can run a macro *0* times, which is not possible in vim since '0' is a command not a count.

This contains many unprintable characters, so here is a hexdump:

```
0000000: 34e9 31c0 f17c 4312 3d12 222a 1222 0a1b  4.1..|C.=."*."..
0000010: 357c 44                                  5|D
```

And here is a readable version:

```
4é1Àñ|C<C-r>=<C-r>"*<C-r>"
<esc>5|D
```

Explanation:

```
4                           " 4 times:
 é1                         " Insert a '1'
   Àñ                       " Arg1 times:
     |                      "   Move to the first character on this line
      C                     "   Delete this whole line and enter insert mode
       <C-r>=               "   Insert the following evaluated as vimscript:
             <C-r>"         "     Insert what we just deleted
                   *        "     Times
                    <C-r>"  "     What we just deleted
<esc>                       "   Escape to normal mode
     5|                     "   Move to the fifth column on this line
       D                    "   And delete until the end of this line
                            " The second 'ñ' is added implicitly
```

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 37 bytes

36 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```pl
$\=1x4;$\=substr$\*$\,0,4while--$_}{
```

To run it:

```
perl -pe '$\=1x4;$\=substr$\*$\,0,4while--$_}{' <<< 80
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Dennis using 1-based indexing and the `ṁ` mold/reshape atom. Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrJE4bmBNOG4jAoxw4fCoQ&input=&args=Mg)

```
²Dṁ4Ḍ
1Ç¡
```

**Ungolfing**

```
Helper link
²       Square.
 D      Integer to decimal (a list of digits).
  ṁ4    Mold/reshape list_of_digits to be 4 digits long.
    Ḍ   Decimal to integer.

Main link: implicit left argument n
1     Start with the nilad 1.
 Ç¡   Call the helper link n times.
```

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39ok8vDnY0mD3f0cBkebj@08P///4YA) saves 3 bytes with 1-based indexing.

Comment: Uh, I don't think you can use `1` instead of `⁽¡n`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How come?

Comment: @Sherlock9 Oh, you seem to 1-index this sequence? Hm, looks like the code is a bit tricky to understand...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 48 bytes

```
Nest[⌊10^(3-⌊t=2Log[10,#]⌋+t)⌋&,1111,#]&
```

Unnamed function taking an integer argument; 0-indexed. Uses four three-byte characters `⌊⌊⌋⌋`: Mathematica uses either `Floor[x]` or `⌊x⌋` to round a real number down to an integer, and the latter is generally one fewer byte. The command names in Mathematica for converting integers to strings are too long, so instead we do a mathematical calculation to find the first four digits of x^2: we take the base-10 logarithm of x^2, subtract its integer part, raise 10 back to that power, and multiply by 1000 and round down.

tl;dr: logarithms ftw

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

-2 (changing the input method) thanks to @Razetime

```apl
{⍎4⍴⍕⍵*2}⍣⎕⊢1
```

Explanation:

```apl
{⍎4⍴⍕⍵*2}⍣⎕⊢1     ⍝ apply the dfn input times
            1     ⍝ .. with initial argument 1
     ⍵*2          ⍝ current value squared
 ⍎4⍴⍕             ⍝ take first 4 digits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97X/1o94@k0e9Wx71Tn3Uu1XLqPZR7@JHfVMfdS0yBCng@p/GZcqVxmVkACQsDAA)

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97X/1o94@k0e9Wx71Tn3Uu1XLqPZR7@JHfVMfdS0yBCng@p/GZcqVxmVkACQsDAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

### Powershell, <s>73</s> 55 bytes

Huge thanks to TimmyD for shaving off 18 bytes!

Code:

`for($A=1111;$args[0]---1;$A=-join"$(+$A*$A)"[0..3]){}$A`

<s>`$A=1111;1..($n=2)|%{[string]$B=[math]::pow($A,2);$A=$B.substring(0,4)};$A`</s>

`$n` is **n** in **x<sub>n-1</sub>**

Explanation and exploded code:

```
$A=1111                            #starting number
$n=4                               #n in formula
for($i=0; $i -lt $n;$i++)          #loop n times
{
    [string]$B=[math]::pow($A,2)   #create a new string $B and set it to $A raised to the power of 2
    $A=$B.substring(0,4)           #set $A to the first 4 characters of $B
}
$A                             #print $A
```

Some notes:

- Powershell lets you assign variables in the same statements where you reference them. For example, `1..($n=4)|%` will set $n to 4 and then start a loop that runs $n times. `1` can be changed to any integer and it will loop $n-[your integer]+1 times.
- The default data type when using `[math]::` in Powershell is a double. In the code above, we have to explicitly cast `$B` to a string so that we can call `.substring()` on it because there is no `.substring()` function for doubles in Powershell.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2,  <s>44</s>   41 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to xnor (use an integer division to avoid `and`)

```python
f=lambda n:int(1/n*1111or`f(n-1)**2`[:4])
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EenM/1)**

1-based recursive function.

When `n>1` the integer division, `1/n`, results in `0`, then `0*1111=0` which is falsey, so the right of the `or` is evaluated, which takes the first four characters of the representation of the square of the `n-1`th result; this is then cast to an `int`.

When `n=1` the integer division, `1/n`, results in `1`, then `1*1111=1111`, which is truthy, and the `int` `1111` cast to an `int` is `1111`.

Comment: Good one, ninja'd me by one byte!

Comment: I just looked for your answer and then realised you wrote the challenge! Nice job.

Comment: Nice idea with taking the `int` outside. If you 1-index, you can do the base case shorter with ``g=lambda n:int(1/n*1111or`g(n-1)**2`[:4])``.

Comment: @xnor very neat!

Comment: "Crossed out 44 still looks like 44 :("

Comment: @Flp.Tkc not as much as it does without the `&nbsp;`s!

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 49 bytes

```
{x=1111;(it-1).times{x="${x**2}"[0..3] as int};x}
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>55</s> 52 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @user59178

```
for($i=1111;$argv[1]--;)$i=substr($i**2,0,4);echo$i;
```

Run from command line, zero-indexed.

Thanks for not caring about what type my variables are, PHP! Here we simply square the number and trim off everything past the first 4 digits, casually alternating between number and string without a care in the world.

Comment: You could save 3 bytes by using `$argv[1]--` as the loop counter.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>14</s>, 13 bytes

```
1111G:"UV4:)U
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTExMUc6IlVWNDopVQ&input=Nw)

Explanation:

```
1111            % Push 1111
    G           % Push input
     :"         % Input times:
       U        %   Square the top of the stack
        V       %   Convert it to a string
         4:)    %   Take the first four digits
            U   %   Convert it back to a number
                % Implictly display
```

Comment: You can use `U` (square, for numeric input) insted of `t*`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for reminding of the function I recommended! :P

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
1RVX`4*4<b
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=1RVX%604%2a4%3Cb&input=5)

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>58</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```
x=3334;for(e in N<-scan():1)x=x^2%/%10^(3+(x>3162));x
```

Takes `N` from stdin. 3334 is practically X_0, which is needed because the for-loop needs to be executed at least once (it would be longer to skip).

R really is a terrible language for taking the first four digits of a number, but since the number of cases are limited, we only have to worry about the squares of `x<3163` and `x>3162`, the former yield a 6 digit number, the latter a 7 digit number.

The rest is pretty straightforward, `%/%` divides and ignores the remainder. `x` is printed to stdout.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions

Comment: This is so notrivial. Brilliant!

Comment: Nice one! What would happen if you started with `3334` (or perhaps `3333`)?

Comment: @ETHproductions `3333^2 = 11108889` so would yield `1110`, and .... as im checking this I see `3334` would work :| . Not sure why I didn't check that anymore.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 20 bytes

```
1111@:2esL4-:.;Kjk;#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/98QCBysjFKLfUx0rfSsvbOyrZX///9vbgkA)

Note this is 1-indexed.

```
            % Implicit: N is on stack
1111@       % Push 1111, and then reverse stack to get [1111, n]
:           % N times do: (this consumes N)
 2e         %   Square last term
 s          %   Split into individual digits
 L4-:.;     %   Get stack length -4, pop that many times
 Kj         %   Join remaining digits (Uses flag "K" for whole stack)
 k          %   Set "K" flag to false, so operations only affect last item
;           % End loop.       
#           % Output final calculated term
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Javagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Javagony) - 153 bytes

Javagony is a restricted version of Java, that doesn't allow any control flow except recursion and `try-catch`, no for loops, while loops, or if's. Coding in it is a pretty fun exercise, but frustrating. Not that regular Java isn't nearly as frustrating by itself.

```
int a(int i){return a(i-1,1111);}int a(int i,int n){try{int x=1/i;return a(i-1,Integer.parseInt((n*n+"").substring(0,4)));}catch(Exception e){return n;}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 14 bytes

```
=1111:(ZZ)[:4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39YQCKw0oqI0o61MYv//BwA)

1-indexed.

### Explanation

```
=1111           first term is 1111
     :          given n, output nth term, otherwise output full sequence
                each term equals
      (ZZ)                       previous term * previous term
          [:4]                                                 [:4] (python slicing)
```

Comment: Really nice showcase of this language's abilities!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
,1111:?:{^@[.l4,}i
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LDExMTE6Pzp7XkBbLmw0LH1p&input=Nzk&args=Wg)

This answer is 0-indexed.

#### Explanation

```
,1111:?:{       }i      Iteratively call Input times the predicate in brackets starting with
                          input 1111:

         ^                  Square
          @[.               Output is a prefix of the square
            .l4,            Its length is 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>64</strike> 60 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes by following [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire)'s [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101961/the-squaring-sequence/101978?noredirect=1#comment247789_101979) on a Java answer!*

```
n=>{int x=1111;for(;n-->1;)for(x*=x;x>1e4;x/=10);return x;};
```

Previous version (**64 bytes**):

```
n=>{int x=1111;while(n-->1){x*=x;while(x>9999)x/=10;}return x;};
```

Full program with ungolfed method and test cases:

```
using System;

namespace SquaringSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int, int> f = n =>
            {
                int x = 1111;
                while (n-- > 1)
                {
                    x *= x;
                    while (x > 9999)
                        x /= 10;
                }
                return x;
            };

            // test cases:
            Console.WriteLine(f(1));    // 1111
            Console.WriteLine(f(8));    // 6840
            Console.WriteLine(f(15));   // 7584
            Console.WriteLine(f(20));   // 1425
            Console.WriteLine(f(80));   // 4717
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the dark goes-to-operator `n-->1`

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 82 bytes

```
@set n=1111
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/an*=n&call set n=%%n:~0,4%%
@echo %n%
```

Like Perl, integers are strings, but unlike Perl I can only take the substring of a variable, and taking substrings inside a loop is somewhat awkward.

Comment: I think you can leave out the space after @for.

Comment: @YourDeathIsComing 'for' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks to @Jakube for -1 byte*

```
us<*4`*GG4Q1
```

A program that takes input of a 1-indexed integer and prints the result.

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us%3C%2a4%60%2aGG4Q1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A8%0A15%0A20%0A80&debug=0)

This uses a similar approach to [@Adnan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101963/55526).

**How it works**

```
us<*4`*GG4Q1  Program. Input: Q
u         Q1  Execute the following Q times, starting at 1, with variable G:
      *GG      Yield G*G
     `          Convert to string
   *4           Repeat 4 times
  <      4      Yield first 4 characters
 s              Convert to integer
              Implicitly print
```

Comment: `*GG` instead of `^G2<space>`

Answer (score 2):

## C, 56 bytes

```
a;s(n){for(a=1111;--n;)a=a*a/(a>3162?1e4:1e3);return a;}
```

One-indexed.

Comment: I have a feeling that you can go for recursion...

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 76 bytes

```clojure
(defn s[n](if(= n 1)1111(read-string(subs(str(*(s(dec n))(s(dec n))))0 4))))
```

First Clojure golf (seems like a nice language). This is 1-indexed.

Will explain the code later.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

First golf! Saves bytes with `-n` option (but still count as 1! :)).

```
a=1111;$_.to_i.times{a="#{a*a}"[0,4].to_i};p a
```

0-indexed.
To run it:

```
ruby -ne 'a=1111;$_.to_i.times{a="#{a*a}"[0,4].to_i};p a' <<< 80
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! One nitpick though, technically this is 47 bytes because of our policy of [counting command line flags](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31716) towards the byte count. Other than that, it looks good to me!

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the rules, answer changed!

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~1111\{.*`4<~}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84QCGKq9bQSTGzqarX@/zcAAA)

0-indexed

```
~                 # Parse n to a number
 1111             # Push 1111
     \{      }*   # Execute this block n times
       .*         # Square the number
         `        # Parse it to a string
          4<      # Get the first 4 digits
            ~     # Parse it back to a number
```

Comment: Nice answer. Is it not possible to take integer input directly?

Comment: @Razetime No, in the input and output section of http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/tutorial.html , it says: "all input from stdin is read first and placed as a string onto the stack". But this site also doesn't mention that the numbers can be complex, so maybe there is a way. If there is, it cannot be shorter than `~`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mh`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
T=Â4î1wT²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1o&code=VD3CNO4xd1Sy&input=ODA)

```
T=Â4î1wT²     :Implicit map of range [0,input)
T=            :Assign to variable T (initially 0)
  Â           :Bitwise NOT of bitwise NOT of (i.e., cast to an integer)
   4î         :Mould to length 4 string
     1w       :  Maximum of 1 and
       T²     :  T squared
              :Implicit output of final result
```

### No Flags, <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

1-indexed, returning a string

```
@4îX*X}g1ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QDTuWCpYfWcx7A&input=ODA)

```
@4îX*X}g1ì     :Implicit input of input of integer U
@              :Function taking an integer X as argument
 4îX*X         :  Mould X*X to length 4
      }        :End function
       g       :Repeatedly take the last element of the following array, pass it through that function, push the result and return the Uth element
        1ì     :  Convert 1 to digit array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Ṫ(²4Ẏ
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaoowrI04bqOIiwiIiwiOCJd), or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmqKMKyNOG6jiIsIiIsIjFcbjhcbjE1XG4yMFxuODAiXQ==).

Explanation:

```
Ṫ      # Pop, push 1 then the input
 (     # [Input] times:
  ²    #   Square
   4Ẏ  #   Get the first 4 digits
```

Comment: With a newly added overload, `1?` can just be `Ṫ`.

Comment: @Steffan Thanks, I was wondering if there wouldd be something like that, I saw that 05AB1E had it.

Comment: [You can decrease it to 4.375 bytes using the `=` flag to compress it using Vyncode.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyI9IiwiIiwi4bmqKMKyNOG6jiIsIiIsIjgiXQ==)

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian Yeah but [we shouldn't be going around old posts just changing it to use Vyncoder](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/106764?m=63474261#63474261)

Comment: @tybocopperkettle oh...

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 31 bytes

```
Input N
1111
For(I,2,N
int(Ans²/₁₀^(-3+int(log(Ans²
End
Ans
```

1-indexed input. `-` represents the negative symbol.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 42 bytes

```
v=1111:For i=2To[A1]:v=Left(v^2,4):Next:?v
```

Input is in cell `A1` of the active sheet. Code is run in the immediate window. Output is to the immediate window. Here's the result for `80` as an input:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>82</s> 59 bytes

Saved 23 bytes thanks to help from commenters @adrianmp and @OlivierGrégoire

```
n->{int x=1111;while(--n>0)for(x*=x;x>1e4;x/=10);return x;}
```

Each iteration, we square the number, then loop and shrink it by factors of 10 until it's a 4 digit number. Repeat this process `n` times and return.

Comment: You can save some bytes by using `x*=x;` instead of `Math.pow`.

Comment: and put that whole stuff in `for` loops instead of `while` loops.

Comment: Taking your algorithm and fixing a lot, I get 60 bytes: `n->{int x=1111;for(;--n>0;)for(x*=x;x>1e4;x/=10);return x;}`. I removed the `y` since we can decrease `n`, I used `for` loops, removed the braces and the biggest winner is what @adrianmp said, of course. Oh, and I made the problem 1-indexed, just like in the question, instead of 0-indexed as in your answer ;)

Comment: you know, I honestly forgot that squaring a number was just `x*x`. I'm too used to the exponentiation operator in PHP `**` and using `Math.pow` in Java. Also, my choice of `while` loops is usually if it doesn't change the byte count, like the first `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
'14*ri{i2#s4<}*
```

Uses 0-based indexing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@69uaKJVlFmdaaRcbGJTq/X/vwkA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>77</s> <s>93</s> <s>74</s> <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 78 bytes

```
int n=1111;int m=1;while(x>m++){n=Integer.parseInt((n*n+"").substring(0,4));}

x->{int n=1111;int m=1;while(x>m++){n=Integer.parseInt((n*n+"").substring(0,4))‌​;}return n;}

x->{int n=1111;for(;--x>0;){n=Integer.parseInt((n*n+"").substring(0,4));}}

x->{long n=1111;for(;--x>0;){n=Long.valueOf((n*n+"").substring(0,4));}}
```

```
x->{long n=1111;for(;--x>0;)n=Long.valueOf((n*n+"").substring(0,4));return n;}
```

Each repetition makes `n` the first 4 characters of `n*n`.

[Try Java online](https://www.compilejava.net/)!

#### Post history:

- 77 bytes: initial code (incomplete)
- +16 bytes, by Olivier Grégoire: completed code by making it a Lambda function.
- -19 bytes: replace `while` with `for` cycle.
- -4 bytes: used `long`s instead of `int`s
- -2 bytes, by Roman Gräf: removed unnecessary brackets
- +9 bytes, missing `return` statement

**[Thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116635/320844) to @OlivierGrégoire and @RomanGräf for pointing out some issues!**

Wait, Java beats... (drumroll) [Clojure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102007/60199) *and* [Matlab](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102032/60199) here! A big applause to Java please!

Comment: This answer is incomplete. `x` isn't declared. This should be a function or full program. Not a code snippet.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I was going for  the function. Seems I missed this out. Do you mean I should just replace x with a number?

Comment: What @NonlinearFruit said is that your answer, with your current code, sould be: `x->{int n=1111;int m=1;while(x>m++){n=Integer.parseInt((n*n+"").substring(0,4));}return n;}` (for a total byte count of 91). This is because snippets aren't allowed: only functions or full programs.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Isn't that 93 bytes? And thanks for pointing out lambda funcions.

Comment: You're right, it's 93 bytes, I must have checked from a previous, defect version. However, all I did was wrapping so that your program would be a valid entry. Now you can golf the hell out of it! For instance, here's a golfed version of your program for only 75 bytes: `x->{Long n=1111;for(;--x>0;)n=n.valueOf((n*n+"").substring(0,4));return n;}`, with several techniques used (used `Long` to be able to use `Long.valueOf` with less bytes, it's not recommended in normal programming, but totally in golfing; removed `m` as it's unnecessary if we decrease `x` instead, removed unneeded braces)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I didn't read your comment as the program wouldn't be mine, but rather yours. I'll try to golf it myself first.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm done golfing. Now when I see your code, I don't think it works: `n=n.valueOf` throws an error; I used `n=Long.valueOf` instead. Also, `return n;` throws an error, and the program works without it.

Comment: You can remove the brackets around `n=Long...`. Also you probably should add a return or the `n` would be useless.

Comment: @RomanGräf it seems to work without it. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: Yes but how do get the result back?

Comment: @RomanGräf You mean print it? I just put a `System.out.println` later.

Comment: I don't see your point. If you add the `System.out.print()` call in the function you have to add that to the byte count.

Comment: @RomanGräf It's not in the function, it's where the function is called

Comment: Then you need a `return`

Comment: @RomanGräf you mean `x->{long n=1111;for(;--x>0;)n=Long.valueOf((n*n+"").substring(0,4));return n}`? It seems to work for me without it.

Comment: Lets say you want to assign `long i=...` to `SquareSequence[n]`. How would `...` look like?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek You are right, I made 1 mistake in my suggestion: `Long n=1111L`: I should have appended `L` (for 1 more byte than advertized). The rest is OK and works fine. Also, make sure to use `Long` and not `long`.

Comment: Also, to be complete, it's still your code: I haven't changed your algorithm for a bit. Same for the other Java answer which [I got down to 60 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101961#comment-247789). I didn't do the main algorithm, so it's not my solution either. I only optimized the presentation of the algorithm itself, just like I suggested for your solution. I don't consider either of suggestions mine.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You could post that golfed-down code as your own answer, get a few upvotes, and leave my partial answer as is. You didn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 36 bytes

```perl6
{(1111,{+$_².substr(0,4)}...*)[$_]}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                 } # bare block lambda
  1111,                  ...        # sequence generator
                            *       # without a limit
       {                }           # lambda used to generate the next value
         $_²                        # start by squaring the previous value
            .substr(0,4)            # take only the first four digits
        +                           # make it numeric ( not necessary )
 (                           )[$_]  # return the requested value
```

### Test:

```perl6
say {(1111,{+$_².substr(0,4)}...*)[$_]}( 1,8,15,20,80 X- 1 ).perl
# (1111, 6840, 7584, 1425, 4717)
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Awk, 41 bytes

Pretty straightforward since you can easily mix math and string manipulations.

```
{for(x=1111;--$1;x=substr(x*x,1,4));}$1=x
```

Accepts zero or more positive numbers *n* (1-indexed), one number per line, on stdin. Outputs results *x<sub>n</sub>*, one result per line, on stdout.

Sample input/output:

```
% awk -f sqrseq.awk
1
1111
8
6840
15
7584
20
1425
80
4717
%
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, <s>79</s>, 78 Bytes

```
function a=s(n)
if n<2;a=1111; else f=s(n-1);a=fix(f^2/10^(3+(f>1e7^.5)));end
```

Test cases:

```
s(79) = 2172
s(49) = 8059
s(6)  = 2876
```

Not an amazing solution. I'm sure there must be a better way to truncate to 4 digits but I don't know today.

Edit: Shaved a byte by setting 0.5 -> .5

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>79</s> <s>67</s> <s>66</s>  64 bytes

- Version 2.2/**64** bytes:

Thanks to @Oliver Grégoire.

```
int a(int i){i=i<2?1111:a(--i);for(i*=i;i>1e4;)i/=10;return i;}
```

- Version 2.1/**66** bytes:

Thanks to @ETHProduction.

```
long a(long i){i=i<2?1111:a(--i);for(i*=i;i>1e4;)i/=10;return i;}
```

- Version 2.0/**67** bytes:

Replaced substring and stuff with the idea from @Xanderhall

```
long a(long i){i=i<2?1111:a(--i);i*=i;for(;i>1e4;)i/=10;return i;}
```

- Version 1.0/**79** bytes:

Although there are shorter solutions I wanted to post one recursive:). And I am the shortest "real" function:). ***Edit:*** Seems like I am the shortest now:)))

```
long a(long i){i=i<2?1111:a(--i);return Long.valueOf((i*i+"").substring(0,4));}
```

Comment: Can you do `for(i*=i;i>1e4;)i/=10;`? That would save a byte.

Comment: Hmmm... Regarding your claim about the shortest Java function, [this function](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101961#comment-247789) would like to have some words ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, thinking about it, why do you even use `long`s? You can kill two bytes by using `int`s.

Comment: I missed that when I updated to 2.0

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 36 bytes

A different approach from the other Perl solution, leading to slightly shorter code. No command-line arguments are needed (other than the usual version selection argument, `-M5.010`, which doesn't count against the byte count), meaning that this is the same amount of code but with fewer penalties, giving a better overall score.

```perl
say+eval'($&*$&||1x4)=~/(....)/;'x<>
```

We create a loop Underload-style via repeating and `eval`-ing a string; I experimented with starting the string in the middle, but starting it at the start turns out to be shortest. We multiply `$&` (the result of the last regex match) by itself to square it; if the result's zero, we use `1x4` (i.e. `1111`; Perl has an operator for repeating things, including digits of a number) instead of the result. Then we regex the first four characters. The whole thing runs in list context due to being inside `say`, thus the final result of the `eval` will be the contents of the parentheses of the final match.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
¡öd↑4d□1111
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DCw9tSHrVNNEl5NG2hIRD8/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å\S∩♪öH╠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=865c53ef0d9448cc&i=1%0A8%0A15%0A20%0A80&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```js
n=>n?(''+f(n-1)**2).slice(0,4):1111
```

Zero-indexed. Outputs a string if n >= 0 and the number 1111 if n == 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMWU0ZiorZiorJHYgL2EsOjElLTExIS58XG46KjokdiE/Oi0xPCRePykrKmYrKmYrKmYyZTZhXG4gO24kPCIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiI4IiwibW9kZSI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==), 59 bytes

```
1e4f*+f*+$v /a,:1%-11!.|
:*:$v!?:-1<$^?)+*f+*f+*f2e6a
 ;n$<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMWU0ZiorZiorJHYgL2EsOjElLTExIS58XG46KjokdiE/Oi0xPCRePykrKmYrKmYrKmYyZTZhXG4gO24kPCIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiI4IiwibW9kZSI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

[image]

## Explanation

Red loop repeatedly squares. Blue subloop divides by 10 while the value is greater than or equal to 10000.

`1e4` is 1111 encoded as base 15. Then repeated `f*+` sums it.

`a6e2` is `10000` encoded as base 15.

I'm not sure if my base 15 encoding is optimal. Maybe some string encoding with base 255 would be better? But then how to properly add the elements? Hmm this could be a [metagolf](/questions/tagged/metagolf) challenge.

Comment: Could you perhaps save some bytes by encoding the a6e2 as U+2710"✐"?

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
1kÆ²░4<i
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98w@3DboU2Ppk00sckE8rgsuAxNuYwMuCwMAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1         # Push 1
 k        # Push the input-integer
  Æ       # Pop and loop that many times, using 5 characters as inner code-block:
   ²      #  Square the current integer
    ░     #  Convert it to a string
     4<   #  Pop and leave the first 4 characters/digits
       i  #  Convert it back to an integer
          # (after the loop, the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 79 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{i,a:=0,1111
for;i<n;i++{for s:=a*a;s>999;s/=10{a=s}}
return a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NasMwEIX3OsVgCNjNpLVCAv6pcoV0n4QyKFYQxXKQ5JXQSboxgR6iR-ltKicZGObBPN73vm-XYfq9kvyiSwc9acN0fx2sf81U77Of0atV9bdXo5GgcgPa-CJt0EiNKJGnYWqwrX43rV4uQ9LgGkEv1LpdXdetexO8DCRcjMx2frQGKD5j9T12huYFBCbJdQ4aAYfTjOBYId_iusSqjDMEPlHOb0smdX24A_uwyazybLE-g9jBYnM-mgxBYuorV7woWGRP4DQ97j8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
«¥[s{²4ɱ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWaw6tPrQ0urj60CaTkxuXFCclF0MlFiwyNIGwAA)

0-indexed.

##### Explanation

```python
«¥[s{²4ɱ  # Implicit input
«¥[       # Push compressed integer 1111
   s{     # Repeat input number of times:
     ²    #  Square top of stack
      4ɱ  #  Take the first four characters
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 42 bytes

```julia
!x=parse(Int,("$(1(x<2||!~-x)^2)"^4)[1:4])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCtiCxqDhVwzOvREdDSUXDUKPCxqimRrFOt0IzzkhTKc5EM9rQyiRW839afpFCpkJmngKQb2hgbWhqbWRgbWEQy6UABAVFmXklOXkamQq2dgqKmZpcqXkp/wE)

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
#1111|:[a-1|f=!A! A=$LEFT$|(!f*f/z$,5)]?A
```

Way too much going on in here... Time to implement Substring in QBIC.

Explanation:

```
#1111|                     Define string constant A$ as '1111'
:                          Get CMD line param for N, called 'a'
[a-1|                      FOR 'b' = 1 to 'a'-1
  f=!A!                    Make 'f' be A$ cast to num

             f*f/z         Square 'f', and since we only want the first 4 digits,
                           divide it by 10 (z=10). This prevents that QBASIC 
                           switches to E^ notation because f^2 is too large
    $LEFT$|(!       $|,5)  Cast it to string, take the first 5 positions (QBASIC 
                           adds a leading space on cast-to-num...)
  A=                       And assign to A$
]                          END FOR
?A                         Print the latest value of A$, end
```

Verified for all test cases.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 28 bytes

```
@:^#0(genc@><""tk4^#0 2)1111
```

Usage:

```
(@:^#0(genc@><""tk4^#0 2)1111)79
```

Simply gets the *n* th item from an infinite list of squaring sequence numbers. Zero-indexed.

More readable:

```
@
  iget #0
    (
      genc@
        join "" tk 4 ^ #0 2
    ) 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
Lao:(o*o)@<4o
```

1-indexed. Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=TGFvOihvKm8pQDw0bw&input=&args=ODA)

#### Explanation

Same algorithm as most of the 1-indexed golflang answers.

```
               Implicit: a is 1st cmdline arg; o is 1
La             Loop a times:
  o:             Assign this expression to o:
         @<4     Leftmost four characters of
    (o*o)        o squared (parens necessary for precedence)
            o  Print final value of o
```

The first step, from `1` to `1111`, works without any explicit string repetition: string slicing in Pip repeats the string as necessary until the slice index is valid. So "leftmost four characters of `1`" gives `1111`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Minkolang v0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 33 bytes

```
'1111'nd?C[2;6ZrI4-[x]r6$Z]N.CxN.
```

**0-indexed**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#@69uCATqeSn2ztFG1mZRRZ4mutEVsUVmKlGxfnrOFX56////NwIA) (for `n=2`)

#### Explanation

```
'1111'                            push this number
      n                           push input as number
       d                          duplicate
        ?                         check if it is 0:
```

If input is `0`: *(the reason `0` has to be handled specially is that otherwise Minkolang gets confused with the for-loops and `0`iterations that you get an error)*

```
         C                        start comment
           ... C                  end comment
                x                 delete value at top of stack (ie 0)
                 N.               output as number and end program
```

If input is `> 0`:

```
         C                        gets jumped over (since input is true)
          [               ]       start for-loop with the input as the number of iterations
           2;                      pushes 2, and raises the number by 2 (ie squares it)
             6Z                    converts number to string
               r                   reverses it
                I4-                pushes the length of the stack (ie the string value of the number) and subtracts it by 4 (so we now how many of the string to discard of)
                   [x]             discard the top of the stack by that many times
                      r            reverses stack
                       6$Z         converts it to a number
                                   for-loop ends
                           N.     output stack as number and end program
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 67 Bytes

Indexed at 1

```
a=1111
for _ in range(int(input())-1):a=str(int(a)**2)[:4]
print(a)
```

I was originally going to do this as a list comprehension, but I realised that I couldn't receive the last item in the list in order to square it.

Comment: Please note that there's already a python answer [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101987/60919).

Comment: @Flp.Tkc I realise that, but both that one and [this one][1] are using python 2, whereas this is python 3, which, i believe, counts as a separate language to the python 2 language, due to slightly different syntax rules. [1]: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101964/53336

Comment: Yes, they're different languages, but there's no point posting a python 3 solution when the python 2 one could just be trivially modified.

Comment: @Flp.Tkc I agree that the Python 2 answers could be modified easily to create a Python 3 answer, but A) This is python, so none of these answers are going to come close to winning (The smallest amount of Bytes that i've seen so far is 7). B) Before posting this answer I didn't look through the current answers, because I do these challenges just to keep my skills up, and I don't want to be influenced by other peoples answers, so I hadn't noticed there were already python answers here

Answer (score 0):

## **C**, <strike>53</strike> 52 bytes

```
a;s(n){return n?(a=s(n-1))*a/(a>3162?1e4:1e3):1111;}
```

Zero based.
First timer - This is a recursive variation on the earlier solution (expressed in the same way), as requested.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Can you remove the outermost parentheses to save a byte? `a;s(n){return n?(a=s(n-1))*a/(a>3162?1e4:1e3):1111;}`

Comment: you can make it one indexed for [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU7RCsIwDHxeviIoQuusWhUfrJsfonso7aYB7aSbvox9@8z0xYOEy@W4xCl3t@E6DNY0Isgulu0rBrSZUuE0KnO7Ejbf6v3mpMvdQZdbedAM0w9TCu7@8iUem9ZTvbzlABRaeFgK4l2Tl9BBwgrSAqP5UevcWa8ZBWbY9axCUtURBfGsDYrREJk3gmSBaYYkMeNuME1JQpI8I@dUYjLzlzDhYGkA/kQUXCrHmZfjdvG9GAtU4xfE5n74AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 44 bytes

```
Stream.iterate(1111)(n=>n*n+"" take 4 toInt)
```

This is an expression which evaluates to a `Stream[Int]`, which is an infinte sequence of integers. In scala, `Stream[A]` extends `(Int => A)`, which means that a Stream is a function from an index to the element at that index.

#### Explantion:

```
Stream.iterate( //create an infinite Sequence,
    1111        //starting with 1111,
  )(            //by calculating the next element with the following function:
    n=>
      n*n       //square the previous element
      +""       //convert it to a string
      take 4    //take the first 4 characters and drop the rest
      toInt     //convert the string back to an int
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 80 Bytes

```
func s(i:Int)->Int{var c=1111;for _ in 0..<i{c*=c;while c>9999{c/=10}};return c}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```
func squaringSequence(index: Int) -> Int {
    var currentNum = 1111

    for _ in 0 ..< index {
        currentNum *= currentNum

        while currentNum > 9999 {
            currentNum /= 10
        }
    }

    return currentNum
}
```

Due to the pretty-verbose nature of string manipulation in Swift, in which converting an Int to a String, getting the first four characters, and converting back might look something like this:

```
let str = String(num);
num = Int(str[str.startIndex ..< str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)])!
```

I'm opting to get the first four digits by dividing by 10 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 19 Bytes

```
~{2^''.4m14¢}\*1\C
```

RProgN continues to be amazing average! Although it easily passes the score of verbose languages, it still chokes in comparison to other golfier languages.

### Explained

```
~{2^''.4m14¢}\*1\C  # Main link
~                    # Zero Space Segment
 {          }       # Define anonymous function
  2^                # Square the top of the stack
    ''.             # Convert to a string.
       4m           # Repeated 4 times.
         14¢        # Push back only the first 4 letters.
             \*     # Multiplied by the implicit input, Creating another anonymous function that calls this one n times.
               1\C  # Push 1 to the stack, and call the chained function.
```

[Try it Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=%7E%7B2%5E%27%27.4m14%C2%A2%7D%5C*1%5CC&input=80)

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 77 bytes

Sequence is zero-indexed. Doesn't work for `n > 1` in TIO because of memory constraints. Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$
¶1111
{`(?!0¶).+
$*
(?<=1¶(1*))1(?=(1*))
1$1$2
^1

M%`1
}`(\d{4}).*$
$1
0¶
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JArCtjExMTEKe2AoPyEwwrYpLisKJCoKKD88PTHCtigxKikpMSg_PSgxKikpCjEkMSQyCl4xCgpNJWAxCn1gKFxkezR9KS4qJAokMQowwrYK&input=MQ)

**Explanation:**

```
$                           # Append a newline and the starting number
¶1111
{`(?!0¶).+                  # Begin loop. If counter is not zero, convert numbers to unary
$*
(?<=1¶(1*))1(?=(1*))        # If the counter >= 1, replace each digit with entire number
1$1$2                       #   (This squares the number)
^1                          # Counter -= 1

M%`1                        # Convert each line's numbers back to decimal
}`(\d{4}).*$                # Keep only first four digits. End loop
$1
0¶                          # Remove the counter
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 70 bytes

```
#(first(drop %(iterate(fn[i](read-string(subs(str(* i i))0 4)))1111)))
```

Zero-based indexing. Iterates a function which returns first 4 characters of the string representation of the squared integer value.

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 52 bytes

```cpp
void s(int&n){n=--n?s(n),n*n/1e3/(n<3163?:10):1111;}
```

Port of [Lynn's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102003/112488) using recursion, is 1 indexed and returns via out parameter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5BDoJADDzTVzSayK6w0Q2JBxb0IeqBLGiaaDELeiG8HYt6tIfpzLSd1D8ext8qvk7Tq6UaO0Xcr1gPXBrDh06xTnnNG9tkG8VFZnfZIbdbnVspN05LYn971g0W1HZ9aKr7HkAi4F4RqzlSwwCROEgpBvellfdHu5U6Y4nDKC5ElzagItHWyRdBCOkU1bwazpjMEktBh0lCGqKo6@s89@2zx6LAMEN84tgB/JksUC2k/cIM0tc0ewFhHxlrOR6nNw)

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 66 bytes

```
(fn(eif x(strse*((fn(* x x))(f(- x 1)))"^...."(m 0)0)1111))
```

There's no `square` unless I import the math lib so `(fn(* x x))` had to do. Using a regex to yank the first four digits.
This is zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 28 bytes

0-indexed.

```
(~:**&2|S|~:[]&4&0|Z)+[1111]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWezTqrLS01IxqgmvqrKJj1UzUDGqiNLWjDYEgFqJkWYGCW7Q5lLNgAYQGAA)

### Explanation

```
(~:** & 2 | S | ~:[] & 4 & 0 | Z) + [1111]

(                               ) + [1111]  # Iterate n times starting with initial value 1111
 ~:** & 2 |                                 #   Square, then
            S |                             #   Convert to string, then
                ~:[] & 4 & 0 |              #   Get first 4 characters, then
                               Z            #   Convert to int
```

Answer (score 0):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 26 bytes

```
{"J"$4#string x*x}/[;1111]
```

## k, 18 bytes

```
{.:4#$x*x}/[;1111]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 76 bytes

```
x=1111
n=int(input())
for y in range(n-1):
    x=int(str(x**2)[:4])
print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWEAi48mwz80o0MvMKSks0NDW50vKLFCoVMvMUihLz0lM18nQNNa24FICgAqyuuKRIo0JLy0gz2sokVpOroAgkWKH5/7@hKQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
"e"b*>$1-:@?!n:*v
%1:,av?  (*"dd":<-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XylVKUnLTsVQ18rBXjHPSquMS9XQSiexzF5BQUNLKSVFycpG9////7plFgA)

**Explanation**

```
                   # we call the input n
"e"b*              # initialize number as 1111
     >$1-:@?!n     # calculate n-1, if 0 then print number
              :*v  # else, square and move to row 2
     v?  (*"dd":<- # if number is less than 10000, move to row 2
%1:,a              # else divide by 10 and mod away the decimals to get an int
```